# mvn test is not working in the same way as in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have this unit tests:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnTheSameStringSinceHasNoAccents() {
    String data = "Hola";
    String expected = "Hola";

    String actual = normalizer.stripAccents(data);

    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}

@Test
public void shouldStripAccent() {
    String data = "¿Qué haces?";
    String expected = "¿Que haces?";

    String actual = normalizer.stripAccents(data);

    assertEquals(expected, actual);
 }
```

I'm using Maven Surefire Plugin. If I do `mvn clean package test` by terminal, I get an error in the second test:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.grupogimeno.parse.util.StringNormalizerTests
Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.039 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests:
  shouldStripAccent(com.grupogimeno.parse.util.StringNormalizerTests)

Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

On the other hand, I have this Maven based Run/Debug Configuration in IntelliJ:

[image]

And when I click on run, both tests pass!

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.grupogimeno.parse.util.StringNormalizerTests
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.093 sec

Results :

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Both ways are using the `M2_HOME` env var to execute `mvn`.

What is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Can this be related to file encoding? Which encoding is used by intelliJ? You can define encoding used by maven with    "-Dfile.encoding=...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be caused by source code encoding, see https://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning and add following property to your pom:

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```